# using google charts with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, charts, jinja2

I'm trying to make a simple line chart with google charts (first time) in my simple  Flask web app. I can't get the chart to show up. Here is my code in my template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {

                      var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
                          data.addColumn('date','date-time');
                          data.addColumn('number', 'chiller_load');
                          data.addRows({{ data | safe }});

                      var options = {
                        title: 'Exchange rate overview',
                        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
                        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
                      };

                      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                      chart.draw(data, options);
         }

</script>
```

now i'm pretty sure the data is being sent to the template as a list-of-lists b/c i can see the list by just putting {{data | safe}} in my template. I also confirmed by running the backend function in jupiter and getting the expected list of lists.
If it helps, here's the function that's fetching and sending the data:

```
def fetch_column(col_name):
    db = get_db()
    column = []
    q_result = db.query('select time_stamp, '+col_name+' from op_data;')
    for measurement in q_result:
        column.append([ measurement['time_stamp'] , measurement[col_name] ])
    return column
```

Comment: Could you post an example of {{ data | safe }} output? It may happen that its format is not valid for JavaScript code.

Comment: If you want to check it's definitely coming out ok in the page you can view source in your browser, that way you'll be able to see if the format looks correct.

Comment: @SergeyShubin sure. Its this: [[datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 0), 17.835], [datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 0, 5), 17.8365],...

Comment: @KeefBaker thanks. I get the above with "inspect element" as well...

Comment: looks like the problem was that i was testing in safari. works fine in chrome :(

Comment: Ah the horror of browser compatibility..

Comment: Try to convert your `datetime` objects (`measurement['time_stamp']`) to ISO format or number of seconds (milliseconds) from 1 January 1970. JavaScript interpreter cannot understand "datetime" in its code. Though it does not explain why this code works in Chrome so I don't post it as an answer yet...

Comment: changing the time stamps type to just 'string' type in the addColumn() method fixes the issues for now.